# Spring Cloud Dataflow routing by JSON header

Tags: json, spring, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have been trying to create a stream with Spring Cloud Dataflow but have not had much luck (mostly due to the lack of documentation).

**Issue 1: Accessing web GUI of dockerized Spring Cloud Dataflow**
I have a dockerized Spring Cloud server running with Kafka on a basic Ubuntu container. For some reason I can't access the web GUI in Windows (at < docker-machine ip >:9393/dashboard). However, I have a separate Docker Ubuntu container running Nginx reverse proxy, which shows up when I go to < docker-machine ip >/index.html or etc. I don't think it is an issue with ports, I have the Spring Cloud container setup with -p 9393:9393 and the port is otherwise unused.

**Issue 2: Routing by JSON Header**
My ultimate goal is to get a file loaded in from Nginx and **routed based on its JSON header** (there are two different JSON headers) and then ingest queries to Cassandra.
I can do all of this except the sorting by JSON header. Which app would you recommend I use?

Answer (score 2):

> Issue 1: Accessing web GUI of dockerized Spring Cloud Dataflow

We might need little more details around this. Assuming this is the local-server, perhaps you could share the docker scripts/image, so we could try it out.

> Issue 2: Routing by JSON Header

The [`router-sink`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tree/master/router/spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-router) application would come handy for this type of use-cases. This application routes the payload to named destinations based on certain conditions, so you'd have the opportunity to route the payload with respective `ingest-query` to Cassandra.

stream 1:

```
stream create test --definition "file | router --expression=header.contains('a')?':foo':':bar’"
```

stream 2:

```
stream create baz --definition ":foo > cassandra --ingest-query=\"query1\""
```

stream 3:

```
stream create wiz --definition ":bar > cassandra --ingest-query=\"query2\""
```

(*where: `foo` and `bar` are named destinations*)